# Is it possible to know if a message was received before?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

When looking at the properties of a SQS message, do any of the message properties indicated if this message has been received before?

I can see that the message has the properties:

1. messageid
2. receipthandle
3. md5ofBody
4. body
5. a list of key/value attributes

From the above I guess it doesn't expose the number of retries?  Because I know there is a setting where you can force the message to go to 'dead letters' if it is retried too many times.

Answer (score 4):

There is a ApproximateReceiveCount and ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp attribute that you can use.

Using the Java SDK you can access the attributes with the `Map<String,String> getAttributes()` method on the `Message` object. E.g. `message.getAttributes().get("ApproximateReceiveCount")`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/Message.html#getAttributes--

Comment: I'm using the java library.  In the console I can see receive count.